# Undefined index HTTP_HOST even though it is checked

Tags: php, apache

Here's the code:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) === TRUE) {
  $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
}
```

How is it possible to get an "Undefined index HTTP_HOST" on the line inside the if statement? I mean, the index setting is checked before it is used.

And why could the HTTP_HOST sometimes be not set?

Comment: Undefined index is not possible in your code. HTTP_HOST is not set if you run php in command line, because this HTTP_HOST is set by web server.

Comment: I'll be mighty surprised if someone tells you that something is wrong with your code. Are you 100% sure the error lies on that line?

Comment: I am 100% sure the error lies on $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; line and I'm very confused. I also thought that the undefined index notice is not possible. That's why I'm asking about this here.

Comment: IDK, can you do a `var_dump($_SERVER)` just to be 101% sure that HTTP_HOST variable is not there?

Comment: @SalmanA I did, and it's just not there. I wish I would understand on what cases the isset function returns TRUE.

Comment: I am at my wits' end. Last thing I want to see is `var_dump(TRUE)`... I hope it does not say `bool(false)` lol...

Comment: This should go straight to PHP Sadness site :)

Comment: Use getenv('HTTP_HOST') instead of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].

Comment: I got an experience with this, using nginx, not apache web server.

Comment: compiling php in some compile application such as phpstorm and etc could cause some nonsense errors

Comment: @Ponting getenv('HTTP_HOST') is worked for me while running from console.

Comment: How is this too localized. Isn't PHP through CLI fairly common? This question and answer helped me solve my similar issue.

Answer (score 41):

Are you using PHP-CLI?

HTTP_HOST works only on the browser.

Comment: How to turn this off in the command line then? It's a NOTICE. I have in my `php.ini` the errors to be only E_ERROR.

Answer (score 5):

A bad implemented browser can omit send que host header information, try this example:

```
telnet myphpserver.com 80
> GET / <enter><enter>
```

in this case $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] not have assigned value, in this case u can use $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] but only if $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] is empty, because no is the same.

Comment: Thanks, The telnet check was the perfect solution to test my app against empty `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. I had tried curl with -H.

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP_HOST must always be set if you are running on a browser... then there is no need to check... simply,

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

is enough

Comment: A lame browser (or a robot) might forget to send the HOST header; the HTTP_HOST variable will not be set in that case.

Comment: You have a typo - paren before the semicolon. I wouldn't recommend not checking.

Answer (score 2):

I would normally omit the `=== TRUE`, as it's not needed here because `isset()` returns a boolean, but that shouldn't stop your code from working.

I would also set $host to a sensible default (depends on your application) *before* the if statement. I have a general rule to not introduce a new variable inside a conditional if it's going to be referred to later.

```
$host = FALSE;    // or $host = ''; etc. depending on how you'll use it later.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
  $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
}
```

Comment: Best practice is to use strict type checking, so I do === TRUE. And the host variable is set to an empty string, yes. I use an error handler, and this error sometimes comes up. The question is not about the working/not working state of the code, but more of a philosophical wondering on why does it happen and how.

Comment: @donkapone "Best practice is to use strict type checking, so I do === TRUE". I have not seen this practiced anywhere. It does not change the codes behavior, performance, and only makes it more verbose and requires more effort to understand. I would take this question to softwareengineering.stackexchange.com or just check out some respected open source projects to see that it's rather unusual.

Comment: This don't answer the OP

Answer (score 1):

When a request is done with an empty host:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host:
```

Then isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) is true!

It is better to use empty like:

```
$host = '';
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
  $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
}
```

For detailed info take a look here https://shiflett.org/blog/2006/server-name-versus-http-host

Comment: is `isset()` returns true there should not be this error "Undefined index HTTP_HOST", that's the whole point of `isset()` check.