# Laravel 5.1 gives 'undefined index: http_host ' when run 'php artisan serve'

Tags: php, laravel-5

I learned `laravel` using `version 5.4` for 6 months. i installed latest xampp then. But now i got to work on a project built on `laravel 5.1`. But when i want to run the app, it gives me the error (undefined index: http_host)! How can i find where the error comes from?
How can i solve the problem? I searched online but nothing found fruitful.
Can you help me, please?
Storage/log.php:

```
[2017-07-18 21:55:50] local.ERROR: ErrorException: Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in H:\Current\school\school\app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php:40
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 H:\Current\school\school\app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php(40): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined index...', 'H:\\Current\\scho...', 40, Array)
#1 [internal function]: Erp\Providers\AppServiceProvider->boot()
#2 H:\Current\school\school\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(507): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 H:\Current\school\school\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(734): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#4 H:\Current\school\school\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(717): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootProvider(Object(Erp\Providers\AppServiceProvider))
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Application->Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(Erp\Providers\AppServiceProvider), 18)
#6 H:\Current\school\school\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(718): array_walk(Array, Object(Closure))
#7 H:\Current\school\school\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->boot()
#8 H:\Current\school\school\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(203): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#9 H:\Current\school\school\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(208): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#10 H:\Current\school\school\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(105): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#11 H:\Current\school\school\artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#12 {main}
```

AppServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()

{

    if(!Session::get(SITE_ID)){
        $subdomain_name = array_shift((explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])));
        if(isset($subdomain_name) && !empty($subdomain_name)){
            $domain = $subdomain_name;
        }else{
            $domain = "school";
        }
        $siteToRecollect = DB::table('site_infos')->where('site_alias',$domain)->first();

        if(isset($siteToRecollect->id) && !empty($siteToRecollect->id) && $siteToRecollect->id != 0){

            Session::put(SITE_ID,$siteToRecollect->id);

        }else{

            Session::put(SITE_ID,1);

        }

    }

}
```

40 line:

```
$subdomain_name = array_shift((explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])));
```

Comment: Post your log instead of autoload please

Comment: Where will i find log file?

Comment: You can found in `storage\logs`, remove every file in here and re-run your artisan command for get error, and open your log file and update your post

Comment: i edited my question @vietnguyen09

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` only work on browser, not PHP-CLI, so when you run command `php artisan` `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` will not exists, you can check here [Undefined index HTTP_HOST even though it is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347048/undefined-index-http-host-even-though-it-is-checked)

In this case, you can fix your code by checking if `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` exists.

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])){
    $gethost = explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    $domain = array_shift($gethost);
}else{
    $domain = "school";
}
```

About lines will solve your issue, and with a bit of improvement. Here is the full version of fixed code and tested.

```
public function boot()
{
    if(!Session::get(SITE_ID)){
        $domain = "school";
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])){
            $gethost = explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
            $domain = array_shift($gethost);
        }
        $siteToRecollect = DB::table('site_infos')->where('site_alias', $domain)->first();
        if(isset($siteToRecollect->id) != 0 && !empty($siteToRecollect->id))
        {
            Session::put(SITE_ID, $siteToRecollect->id);
        }else{
            Session::put(SITE_ID,1);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help,

Comment: thanks it works! can you please explain what the code does? As i said it is not my task but i am going to work on it. i have table 'site_infos' which has 'site_alias' column. What i know that a boot method runs every time page load. so, what the code in the boot method does?

Comment: You can read from here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/providers but anyway I think you should find another way to do this instead of send a query to your database for every request, this is bad.

Comment: what should i do instead  of that?

Comment: It depends on your system, if your data in table `site_infos` is not too many, you can put them into the config and read from there. If your table has too many rows, you should use `memcache` or `redis` to store them and read them instead.

Comment: My site_infos table is not too large.  I don't know how can i put in config and use this every time page loads. don't know about memcache or redis. Do you have any link from where i can learn those?

Comment: You can read about Laravel config here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#accessing-configuration-values `memcache` document here: https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki and the last one `redis`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redis

Comment: remember the project is in 5.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149696/discussion-between-vietnguyen09-and-fawel).